# In Django, how to show admin messages in my own views?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

In my Django, I'm integrating the admin for some utility functions, e.g. linking directly to a specific admin page to edit a model and overriding the ModelAdmin `response_change` method to redirect back to my own view when the user clicks save.

This is working nicely -- except the admin's messages (e.g. "such and such a model was saved" or whatever) aren't showing up in the `messages` template context variable, as messages normally do when you use `message.success(...)` etc.

How do I get the admin's messages to show up like a normal message, or how can I otherwise access those messages in my own templates?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show custom message in admin using `response_change` then use

```
messages.info(request, 'Model was changed successfully.')
```

If you are using your own views, then use following code. It worked for me.

```
messages.success(request, ("Model added successfully"), fail_silently=True)
```

Then if you use your custom tempalte, use the following in your template.

```
{% if messages %}
    <div align='center'>
        <ul id="message" >
            {% for message in messages %}
                <ul{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{message}}</ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm asking is NOT how to create my own custom messages, but how to show the messages the admin already generates in my own templates, after redirecting from the admin to my own views via `response_change`.

Comment: You need to use your own message when using `response_change` as the default message will not be displayed.